# The callback getContactsAsync() exists in module ExponentContacts, but only one callback may be registered to a function in a native modules

Tags: react-native, expo

I've got a piece of code that uses `Expo.Contacts.getContactsAsync()` to get the list of contacts from the phone. I only ask for `PHONE_NUMBERS`.

On the list returned, I check of there's an image available, and if so, I use `Expo.Contacts.getContactByIdAsync` with the `THUMBNAIL` option.

All this works fine in iOS, but on Android, I get the above error, and I have no clue what to do, and why it happens.

If people want to see the code I can replicate it here, but - as I said - it works fine on iOS, so I'm looking for advice on what this message means.

Comment: My wild guess is that you are using a state variable in the function you are registering for the native module, you should share your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that contact ids are integers in Android, and strings in iOS.
Do not get those confused in your own code, or strange things like this will happen.

I ended up converting all Android integer ids into strings, before accepting them into my own code.